# InvokeCommandAction from DataTemplate not firing?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to use InvokeCommandAction in a DataTemplate to hook a view event to an ICommand in the DataContext view model however the command execute method is never invoked. If I raise the event and handle in the view code behind then I get the expected behaviour...

**Parent view**

```
  xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

 <DataTemplate x:Shared="False" DataType="{x:Type sensors:CleanSensorsViewModel}">
      <local:CleanTimeSeriesView>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
              <i:EventTrigger EventName="IsVisibleChanged">
                 <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SensorTabVisibilityChangedCommand, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
              </i:EventTrigger>
          </i:Interaction.Triggers>
     </local:CleanTimeSeriesView>
  </DataTemplate>
```

**Control in the view using the DataTemplate**

```
<docking:DockSite Grid.Column="2" 
                              ToolItemsSource="{Binding MeasuredSignalViewModels}"
                              NewWindowRequested="OnNewTabRequested"
                              WindowsClosed="OnWindowsClosed"
                              AreNewTabsInsertedBeforeExistingTabs="False"
                              ToolItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource StyleSelector}">
                <docking:Workspace>
                    <docking:TabbedMdiHost ContainersHaveNewTabButtons="True" TabOverflowBehavior="ScrollWithMenu" />
                </docking:Workspace>
            </docking:DockSite>
```

The DataTemplate CleanSensorsViewModel is an item in MeasuredSignalViewModels

**Data template's view model (CleanSensorsViewModel)**

```
 public ICommand SensorTabVisibilityChangedCommand { get; set; }

 private void InitialiseCommands()
 {           
   this.SensorTabVisibilityChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.ExecuteSensorTabVisibleChangedCommand);
 }

 private void ExecuteSensorTabVisibleChangedCommand()
 {
   //Breakpoint here
 }
```

I have turned on tracing (see xaml) & this is what I get in the output window

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=27231335) 
for Binding (hash=58769117)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 
'SensorTabVisibilityChangedCommand'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): Default 
mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): Default 
update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): Attach 
to System.Windows.Interactivity.InvokeCommandAction.Command (hash=66182225)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 64 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): Use 
Framework mentor <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): 
 Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 69 : BindingExpression 
(hash=27231335):Framework 
mentor not found
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): Resolve 
source deferred
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): Got 
InheritanceContextChanged event from InvokeCommandAction (hash=66182225)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): 
Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 69 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): 
Framework mentor not found
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): Got 
InheritanceContextChanged event from InvokeCommandAction (hash=66182225)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): 
Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): Found 
data 
context element: CleanTimeSeriesView (hash=46207013) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): 
Activate with root item CleanSensorsViewModel (hash=15858029)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335):   At 
level 0 - for CleanSensorsViewModel.SensorTabVisibilityChangedCommand found 
accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(SensorTabVisibilityChangedCommand)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): 
Replace 
item at level 0 with CleanSensorsViewModel (hash=15858029), using accessor 
RuntimePropertyInfo(SensorTabVisibilityChangedCommand)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): 
GetValue 
at level 0 from CleanSensorsViewModel (hash=15858029) using 
RuntimePropertyInfo(SensorTabVisibilityChangedCommand): DelegateCommand 
(hash=20998208)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): 
TransferValue - got raw value DelegateCommand (hash=20998208)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=27231335): 
TransferValue - using final value DelegateCommand (hash=20998208)
```

I far as I can tell this binding is resolved correctly? I don't get any binding errors at all however the breakpoint in the execute on the view model is never invoked. Is there something I'm missing here? Is there a potential timing issue with the control in the data template not being resolved at the time of the binding being resolved?

Comment: when InitialiseCommands is called?

Comment: Hi, from the viewmodel constructor, it is being initialised as expected

Comment: How do you change the Visibility?

Comment: Ok so the view in the DataTemplate is used by a dock site so this view sits in docking tab. Visibility is changed when the tab comes in/out of view to the user. The IsVisibleChanged event is on the tab object rather than the user control defined in the CleanTimeSeriesView defined in the DataTemplate. The DataTemplate is resolving a tab within the docking framework at run time. Edited question, thanks